# How to get "Outcome" value and manage rule to move document to another folder in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I want to create a rule in a folder which monitoring the (final) Outcome task of a workflow and move the document to another folder. I use the modified basic template of Pooled review which found in Repository > Data Dictionary > Scripts directory (start-pooled-review-workflow.js).

The rule I created was:

+++++++++

**When:**

Items are updated

**If all criteria are met:**

Outcome contains 'Task Done'

*--Outcome is equal to bpm:outcome name. From "Show more.." menu selection.*

**Perform Action:**

Move items to ...

+++++++++

But I can't get the value of the final outcome as expected: **Task Done**.
Hence the rule is never move the document to another folder.

I also found similar problems on Alfresco forum:

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/end-user-discussions/alfresco-share/how-manage-rule-move-approved-files-another-folder

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/triggering-rule-when-document

Anyone could give me a clue on this? How to proper way to capture final status/outcome of a workflow?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is confusing me is that you are talking about folder rules but you are trying to check a workflow outcome, which is part of the workflow, not part of the document. Unless you have something in your workflow that sets a property on the document, you won't be able to do what you're doing from a rule.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. It really open my basic understanding about documents and workflows, since I'm new on this. I will try your suggestions.

One more question, where's the script of workflow which I can set a property of document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read and work through [this tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html) on advanced workflows.

One of the examples included in that tutorial is how to run an action on every document in a workflow package. The code snippet looks like this:

```
<userTask id="usertask4" name="Approved Notification" activiti:assignee="${initiator.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="scwf:activitiApprovedNotification">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
            <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>
                    var setWebFlagAction = actions.create("set-web-flag");
                    setWebFlagAction.parameters["active"] = true;
                    for (var i = 0; i &lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++) {
                        logger.log("Approving node:" + bpm_package.children[i].nodeRef);
                        setWebFlagAction.execute(bpm_package.children[i]);
                    }
                </activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

In this example, the code will run when the "Approved Notification" task is created for the user. The JavaScript is running the action.

In your case, if you just want to set a property, you don't need to run an action. You can just use the [JavaScript API](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/API-JS-ModifyCreate.html) to set the property. It would be something like this:

```
<userTask id="usertask4" name="Approved Notification" activiti:assignee="${initiator.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="scwf:activitiApprovedNotification">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
            <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>
                    var setWebFlagAction = actions.create("set-web-flag");
                    setWebFlagAction.parameters["active"] = true;
                    for (var i = 0; i &lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++) {
                        var doc = bpm_package.children[i];
                        doc.properties["cm:description"] = "Set via workflow";
                        doc.save();
                    }
                </activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

Here I am setting the description, but it could be any property, including a custom property.

At that point you could have a rule configured to do something when that property is set a certain way.

These example put code in a user task. Activiti also lets you have tasks that are basically just script execution, so you don't have to assign a task to a human just to run some script. These are called service tasks. Here is an example:

```
<serviceTask id="exampleServiceTask" name="Example Service Task" activiti:class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.script.AlfrescoScriptDelegate">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:field name="script">
      <activiti:string><![CDATA[
          logger.log("Just an example");
      ]]></activiti:string>
    </activiti:field>
  </extensionElements>
</serviceTask>
```

Between the docs, this answer, and the workflow tutorial you should have what you need.

Comment: Thanks so much, and I already read and practice your tutorial. God bless you! (y)